# Error with dlib installation in Windows 10 with Anaconda and Python 3.7.3

Tags: windows, windows-10, python3, anaconda

I am new to Python and I am trying to install [dlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwfOI.jpg) in my environment with the command:

```
pip install dlib
```

but I am receiving the following error:

*ex. Error in Anaconda Prompt*

[image: Error in Anaconda Prompt - Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, welcome to superuser! Could you provide the text of the error instead of a screenshot? It makes helping you a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error in your screenshot, your version of Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2013) is too old. `dlib` apparently needs support for C++11 which is identified as being a part of Visual Studio 2015 and later.